# Current consumption of telematic device

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, pcb, current

I have been working on this telematic device. It has Bluetooth, WiFi, LTE, and so on. The device is used for evaluation of GPS data and recording the GNSS value and all other information regarding satellite system. This device uses battery (Li-ion) with capacity of 1950 mAh and 3.6 V. Now I need to reduce current consumption of this device during sleep and deep sleep mode. Currently it consumes 7 mA when we give 12 V power and 17 mA at 24 V power.

Is it possible to bring down current consumption down to 1 mA during sleep mode and 4 or 5 mA at deep sleep mode?

Comment: Welcome! Please add a link to relevant datasheets.

Comment: As reducing power consumption is dependent on both firmware and hardware, please share the details of the hardware like the schematics and what you're currently doing to reduce power in firmware.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why does it use more power in *deep sleep* mode then in *sleep* mode

Comment: D Duck it uses more power in sleep mode as it uses rechargeble LI-ion battery and even in sleep and deep sleep mode there are some activities running in background because of which there is current consumption

Comment: EarthLoard -Actually i am doing thesis research on this device , its a telematic device and it has Li-ion battery in it because of which we need to let the device off when the vehicle is not moving or in rest . so the problem is when we let device in sleep mode the power consumption is way high then we expect it to be , so my work is to reduce that power consumption as low as i can ,